# ActiveRecord querying since date X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Post` and a`Comment` model. I'm trying to retrieve posts that DO have comments, but DO NOT have any comments since date X.

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:comments).where('comments.created_at < ?', 1.month.ago)
```

This query successfully retrieves posts with comments before date X, but does not ensure there are NO comments since date X.

A better approach would probably be querying the last comment for each post and comparing against date X. But is this possible in one query?

Comment: You're probably going to have to test vs. `MAX(comments.created_at)` using a `group` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The following query looks a bit long and complicated, but its the only way I could come up to get the result you are looking for. It will return Posts that have comments that are not more recent than 1 month ago, and also there are no comments for the same post since 6 months ago:

```
@posts = Post.all.joins(:comments).where('comments.created_at < ?', 1.months.ago).where('NOT EXISTS (select * from comments where created_at > ? AND post_id = posts.id)',6.months.ago).references(:comments)
```

It will produce the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" WHERE (comments.created_at < '2014-09-24') AND (NOT EXISTS (select * from comments where created_at > '2014-04-24' AND post_id = posts.id))
```

According to my tests it should return the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:comments).where("comments.created_at::date < ?", 1.month.ago)
```

Comment: remove **::date** in the above example and check

Answer (score 0):

This will give all posts that have comments not between 1 month ago and now (so older than 1 month):

```
Post.includes(:comments).where.not(comments: { created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.month)..Time.now.midnight })
```

If this isn't exactly what you are looking for, perhaps an example of a post that fits the criteria, and one that does not (assume that they have comments since you were explicit on that).